# Using the Move_base package with only a local planner

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm currently designing a mobile robot that is required to follow an object within 2 meters. Currently, the mobile robot is able to identify the object, its distance from the object, and its orientation with respect to the object - this is enough information for me to set a navigation goal relative to the mobile robots location. The robot will be following the object into unknown environments, we can assume these environments will not be mapped.
For this application I believe it should be satisfactory to use a local planner to reach the short distance goal while avoiding any obstacles along the way.
I would like to take advantage of the dwa_local_planner package within the move_base package but I am unsure if move_base can be used without a global planner and without a map.

I would appreciate any advice,
Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264278/using-the-move_base-package-with-only-a-local-planner/) by [tgilmour](https://answers.ros.org/users/25907/tgilmour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although you can use move_base to follow a moving target, that is not the best approach because, as the goal changes, the move_base will abort the current motion, replan and execute.

check this related question, there are several interesting answers to this problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/28950/what-is-the-best-way-to-follow-a-moving-target/

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tgilmour](https://answers.ros.org/users/25907/tgilmour/) on 2017-06-21**:
Thanks for linking your previous question, there is some good information on that thread. I was never intending on using a global planner as you suggested in your question, only the local planner - which apparently is used in the "controlling" state.